# How to Handle "" type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' "" errror in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have problem with this error:
type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
this is my model code:

```
class LoginUserModel {
  final id;

  LoginUserModel({@required this.id});

  factory LoginUserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return LoginUserModel(
      id: json['id'],
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    return data;
  }
}
```

also my id gets String and reponse boolean.
my hole error:

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device iPhone 12 mini...
Restarted application in 4,667ms.
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
#0      LoginPage.build.<anonymous closure>.fetchLogin (package:amlake_shaar_main1/loginUser.dart:103:74)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: The error message is very clear. ```LoginUserModel.fromJson``` requires an input type of ```Map<String,dynamic>``` but you have provided a ```boolean``` value to it.

Comment: Can you help me with an example or with details? Thanks dadash.

Comment: This is not the part of your code that is causing the problem, it when you are calling toJson or fromJson somehwere else in your code. Post that part

Comment: This can be a valid input for your constructor. ```Map<String, dynamic> userData = {'id': 1};```. Pass it to your constructor. ```LoginUserModel myModel = LoginUserModel.fromJson(userData);```

Comment: Still not understand! I did your code and still have a problem

Comment: The code you provided is not enough. I need to see the code where you instantiate your object.

Answer (score 0):

The instantiate part of code:

```
                              final ID = _controller.text.toString();
                              final url = "https://api.shaarapp.ir/api/User/CheckHasUser?id=$ID";
                              Future<LoginUserModel> fetchLogin() async {
                                final response = await http.get(url);
                                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                                  return LoginUserModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
                                } else {
                                  throw Exception('Failed');
                                }
                              }
                              FutureBuilder<LoginUserModel>(
                                future: fetchLogin(),
                                builder: (context, snapshot){
                                  if(ID == snapshot.data.id.toString() && snapshot.data.id.toString() == true){
                                    print(url);
                                  }else{
                                    print('not');
                                  }
                                },
```

Comment: Can you print the body of your response?

Comment: I recommend removing your api link.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
in my case, you don't need a model because my response of json is not an object, it's just a boolean.